# HBase shell crash after backspace

Tags: shell, docker, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am running HBase in a docker container.
Version is 1.2.4

Basically based on

> https://github.com/dajobe/hbase-docker

When i do the following:

1) Build the image: **docker build -t hbase-docker .**

2) Start the container: **./start-hbase.sh**

3) Go in the container: **docker exec -it hbase bash**

4) Open HBase shell: **hbase shell**

5) and then if i type something and press backspace, it crashes with following:

```
hbase(main):001:0> ConsoleReader.java:1414:in `backspace': java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    from ConsoleReader.java:1436:in `backspace'
    from ConsoleReader.java:628:in `readLine'
    from ConsoleReader.java:457:in `readLine'
    from Readline.java:237:in `s_readline'
    from Readline$s$s_readline.gen:65535:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:332:in `cacheAndCall'
    ...
    ...
```

Any idea how to make backspace work and prevent this from happening?!
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ssh to your docker container or connect to it in browse mode and check the number of columns set for the terminal using -

`stty -a`

You will see something like below in output -

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 39; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
```

Your shell might be crashing when number of column is set to zero, its a known jLine bug. Check following links for reference - https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/151, https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/714

To fix the issue just set number of columns > 0 like below -

```
stty columns 50
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I never thought i'd figure out this, but appreciate your help and clear answer. @mbaxi

Answer (score 1):

this is the problem of GUI problem, you need resize the terminal window to max size.